# Что значат параметры в URL картинок?

Tags: php

Нашёл в коде сайта ссылку:

> `http://domain.com/logo.jpg?version=white`

Это значит, что картинки в этом проекте в базе хранятся? Если нет, то какие ещё есть варианты?

Comment: Спрашивайте автора сайта, а не нас

Comment: @andreymal согласен, но скорее всего это картинка генерится скриптом

Comment: @Naumov, генерировать лого? о_О Это же лого. Скорее всего их где-то лежит несколько штук и одно из них выдаётся.

Comment: @Naumov если исправить "спрашивайте автора сайта" на "спрашивайте автора скрипта", смысл не изменится :)

Comment: я че то хз, с чего вы тут решили закрыть вопрос. кто-то не с той ноги встал? Вопрос достаточно общий и спрашивает об общем принципе динамической генерации изображений.

Comment: @teran  вопрос слишком общий Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. Не задавайте сразу несколько вопросов. См. «Как задать хороший вопрос?» для прояснения ситуации.

Comment: @teran то, что это якобы генерация изображений - лишь ваша ничем не подкреплённая догадка, этот параметр может значить абсолютно что угодно, в том числе ничего не значить

Comment: @andreymal дак вот это и надо объяснить спрашивающему. Вопрос так и звучит "что значат параметры в url изображения". То есть не "что значит конкретный параметр в пример"е, а "для чего они вообще могут быть использованы".

Comment: @teran если интерпретировать вопрос так, то его всё равно надо закрыть как слишком общий :) Для чего захочется - для того и использовать.

Comment: @andreymal с чего вдруг он будет слишком общий? на него можно дать весьма конкретный ответ, что ресурс может быть статичным или динамическим. Динамический ресурс генерируется серверным кодом. - Я двумя предложениями дал ответ на этот вопрос. Он тут не подразумевает бесконечную дискуссию с непонятными ответами, чтобы попасть под категорию "Слишком общий вопрос"

Comment: @teran даже если вы и правы, вопрос всё равно требует правки, чтобы его можно было так интерпретировать

Answer (score 1):

Каждая запрошенная URL соответствует некоторому ресурсу на стороне сервера (или его отсутствию). Ресурс может быть как статическим (файлы, в т.ч. html-страницы, изображения, документы), так и строится динамически. Сайт может быть построен как в виде набора статичных html-страниц, так и используя некоторый язык программирования на стороне сервера, в результате отдающий все тот же html-контент.

При запросе изображений ситуация не изменяется. Запрошенное изображение может быть файлом размещенным по указанному пути, а может отдаваться клиенту динамически.

Часто (но далеко не всегда) наличие get-параметров в url свидетельствует о том, что доступ осуществляется не к файлу изображения, а к php скрипту (или другому серверному коду), который возвращает контент запрашиваемого изображения. Откуда скрипт берет изображение (из файла на диске, базы,  или удаленного ресурса) в данном контексте уже не важно.

Перенаправление запроса (сопоставление исходной URL `logo.png?version=white`) и его сопоставления конечному файлу-скрипта в простейших случаях выполняется такими способами как директивы `RewriteRule` для апача, либо другими механизмами маршрутизации на уровне приложения.

В то же время, отсутствие параметров не означает, что ресурс статичный. Как и наличие параметров не свидетельствует о его "динамичности". В общем говоря, вид URL вообще никак не говорит нам о том, какова природа запрашиваемого ресурса.

Динамическая генерация контента изображений может применяться для:

- ограничения доступа к файлам
- скрытие пути к конечному файлу
- ресайза изображения "на лету", наложения водяных знаков и т.п.

Использование get-параметров для статичных файлов:

- ограничения кэширования на стороне клиента (в url  прибавляют метку времени а-ля `logo.png?t=1233123123`)

Comment: что гадать то? t

Comment: @Naumov а кто гадает-то? Человек вообще видимо не в курсе, что изображение может быть отдано динамически. Я не гадаю ведь, что конкретно происходит на данном сайте. А говорю для чего это может применяться в принципе. Если у вас какие то проблемы с этим вопросом, то не стоит из-за этого минусить всех, кто попробовал объяснить суть принципа.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего это не значит. Просто на сервере настроен ролутинг, который обрабатывает этот адрес с параметром и что-то (что угодно) делает дальше.

Comment: Ну и за что минус?

Comment: Это я влепил, ответ явно на коменнтарий тянет :D

Comment: @Naumov, почему? А что должно тянуть на ответ (а не комментарий) в этом вопросе?

Comment: Почему бы тогда не сделать logo_white.jpg logo_black.jpg и т.д. в чём смысл обработки такого динамического параметра на сервере?

Comment: Так это сугобо моё субъективное мнение, ибо вопрос явно не по теме ru.stackoverflow, а значит не может иметь конкретного ответа.

Comment: p.s. если тебя напрягает минус могу убрать :-D

Comment: @fosh4455, возможно, так подставляется тема и её проще везде одинаково использовать, чем делать какие-то исключения.

Comment: @Naumov, как хочешь) Просто было неожиданно.

Answer (score 0):

Часто все запросы на сервер перехватываются. Если даже идет адрес `site.com/files/directory/image.png`, абсолютно не факт, что на сервере существует папка `files`, `directory` и вообще картинка `image.png`. Вполне возможно, что всё это будет формироваться серверной стороной  (например скриптом на PHP) на лету. И для каких-то целей, можно придумать какие-то параметры.

Я, например, на сайтах использую хелпер для картинок, который принимает значения высоты и ширины из адресной строки. Т.е. в html пишу

```
<img src="/images/300/400/imageName.png" alt="">
```

При этом папки `images` на сервере нет. Запрос перехватывается и обрабатывается контроллером фреймворка. В моем случае - ресайз и выдача картинки. Можно было бы написать так:

```
<img src="/images/imageName.png?w=300&h=400" alt="">
```

И обработать немного по другому параметры. Смысл бы не поменялся.

Comment: что гадать то? t