# Не понимаю как вставить картинку

Tags: bootstrap

Может кто нибудь объяснить как вставить сюда картинку(Bootstrap) и что означает весь этот код auto&bg&fg

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src=".../800x400?auto=yes&bg=555&fg=333&text=Third 
slide" alt="Third slide">
```

Comment: измените `src` на то что вам надо и все.

Comment: по поводу _всего этого_, был схожий вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/721258/223826

Answer (score 0):

В данном коде
class:

d-block - означает блочное отображение (можно d-inline\d-flex и т.д.)

w-100 - означает ширина 100% (можно 25\50\75\100), так есть вариант mw-*, h-* и т.п.

src="..." - тут в кавычках путь к вашему изображению и ответ на ваш вопрос как поменять.

Вам необходимо почитать [инструкцию](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/) бустрапа